# Programmatically color format numeric columns in a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am looking to color format each numeric column so that it shows a blue range bar depending on the range of each column. Here is a photo on what I am trying to achieve. [image]

```
#Here is the the table I have so far.
#I am adding filters to the columns. This works great

library(DT)
library(magrittr)
df = datatable(iris, filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE))

#I try to add the blue bars here to the first 2 numeric columns

df %>%formatStyle(names(df)[1:2],
            background = styleColorBar(range(df[,1:2]), 'lightblue'),
            backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
            backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition = 'center')
Error in df[, 1:2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

It would also be nice if there was a function to automatically place the blue bars on all numeric columns. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can improve:

- Programatically define numeric columns (pass `sapply(iris, is.numeric)` result).
- To format style you need to pass original table (`iris` instead of `df`). `df` might have different columns, because of row-names.
- To `styleColorBar` also pass original table instead of `df`.

Code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)

# Specify numeric columns
foo <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)

datatable(iris, filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE)) %>%
    formatStyle(names(iris)[foo],
            background = styleColorBar(range(iris[, foo]), 'lightblue'),
            backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
            backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot Po!! Do you know if there is a way to compare the range of each individual column rather than the range of the whole data frame? For example, .2 in petal width might actually be large compared to the petal width range.

Comment: @JordanWrong It might be done by scaling data columnise. Can you post this as a new question because this is very different from your original problem

Comment: I have added a new thread, if you have time, please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950917/programmatically-color-format-numeric-columns-by-each-column-range-in-datatable