# Programmatically Color Format Numeric Columns by Each Column Range in Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I opened a thread about how to add range bars in a datatable here:[Programmatically color format numeric columns in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943418/programmatically-color-format-numeric-columns-in-a-datatable).

However instead of fitting the  ranges based on the whole data frame, I would like to format based on the range of each individual column. I figured out some code that works, however, it is most definitely daunting and not programmatic.

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)

# Specify numeric columns
foo <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)

datatable(iris, filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE)) %>%
  formatStyle(names(iris)[foo][1],
              background = styleColorBar(range(iris[, 1]), 'lightblue'),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center') %>%
  formatStyle(names(iris)[foo][2],
              background = styleColorBar(range(iris[, 2]), 'green'),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a start which plots it for every numeric column in the dataset. You can modify is to fit a specific use case.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(RColorBrewer)

colorbarTable = function(table,colorscale){
  num = sapply(table,is.numeric) #Find which columns are numeric
  colors = brewer.pal(sum(num),colorscale) #Define the number of colors

  DT = datatable(table,filter = 'top',options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE)) #Define the base data table

  for(i in seq_along(num)){
    if(num[i]){
      #If numeric add to the datatabls
      DT = DT%>%
        formatStyle(names(table)[i],
                    background = styleColorBar(range(table[,i]), colors[i]),
                    backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                    backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                    backgroundPosition = 'center')
    }
  }

  return(DT)
}


colorbarTable(mtcars,"Pastel1")
```

Tested it with the `iris` and `mtcars` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to awesome answer by @Sada93.

If you want to apply different colours on selected columns, then try this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


colorbarTable = function(table, 
                         colorVarList){

    # TESTING
    # table = tempDf
    # vcolorVarList = list(lightblue = c('var2'), lightgreen = c('var3'), pink =  c('ID')

    index <- enframe(colorVarList) %>% 
        unnest %>%
        rename(color = name, colName = value) %>%
        as.data.frame

    dTable <- DT::datatable(table, 
              filter ='top',
              extensions = list('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), 
              options = list(
                  list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                             buttons = list('copy', 'print', 
                                            list(extend = 'collection', buttons = c('csv', 'excel'), text ='Download')
                                            )),
                  list(dom = 't', 
                       scrollX = F,
                       fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1, rightColumns = 2)))) 

  for(i in 1:nrow(index)){

      # TESTING 
      # i = 1   
  colName <- index[i,"colName"]; colorName <- index[i,"color"]
      dTable <-  dTable%>%
        formatStyle(colName,
                    background = styleColorBar(base::range(table[,colName]), colorName),
                    backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                    backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                    backgroundPosition = 'center')

    }

  return(dTable)
}


tempDf <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                  var3 = c(1,2,3,3,5))

colorbarTable(table = tempDf,
              colorVarList = list(lightblue = c('var2'),
                                  lightgreen =  c('var3'),
                                  pink =  c('ID')))
```